# Как использовать простаивающий поток?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

У меня есть некая база данных, которую раз в час мне нужно проверять. Я думал выделить отдельный поток, который будет раз в 3600 секунд делать проверку, но потом до меня дошло, что я собираюсь выделить **целый** поток, который 99.9% своего времени будет простаивать в ожидании (sleep). Есть ли какой-нибудь более рациональный сделать такой механизм проверки, без необходимости выделять целый поток на это? И есть ли способ, пока поток простаивает перенаправить его ресурсы на более важные задачи? Вот пример кода:

```cs
class Program
{
        static void CheckDataBase()
        {
            //... some code
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread DataCheck = new Thread(CheckDataBase);
            DataCheck.Start();
            //... some code
        }
}
```

И ещё у меня небольшой вопрос. Как программа на wpf или формах понимает когда была нажата кнопка?
Там же не используется какой то механизм, который каждую миллисекунду проверяет не нажата ли кнопка? И как я знаю там вызывается делегат метода, который реализует логику кнопки прямо в момент нажатия, без посредников в виде бесконечных циклов, или я не прав? И если это так, то как это сделано?

Comment: Таймер же. Пока таймер ждет - никакой поток не выделяется. Или await Task.Delay() (внутри которого тот же таймер)

Comment: То есть пока идёт Sleep у потока, он переключается сам на более важные дела?

Comment: Да, операционная система по кругу крутит потоки, переключаясь между ними. Спящий поток не активируется и не забирает процессорное время. Как по мне, лучшая реализация периодической задачи - однократный таймер на выполнение функции, в конце которой таймер заново запускается. Так можно сделать опрос БД через заданный интервал.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Когда поток висит на sleep-е, то он не использует ресурсы процессора. Ну, почти не использует, так как строчку во внутренних таблицах ОС поток все-таки занимает и ОС периодически проверяет эти таблицы и анализирует, не пора ли запустить поток. А вот память даже остановленный поток занимает. Но на это приходится идти, так как по-другому не сделаешь.

Comment: Окей. Это я понял, а что насчёт волшебных делегатов в WPF?

Comment: @Влад Бочкарёв Насчет делегатов как там внутри сделано это известно только Микрософту. Вряд-ли там опрос, скорее всего по событию нажатия они смотрят, какая кнопка нажата.

Comment: @ВладБочкарёв нет никакой магии. Событийная модель. Сработал таймер - был вызван обработчик - и только тогда был занят какой то поток. Нажали лкм - операционная система шлет сообщение окну WM_LBUTTONDOWN - окно вычисляет куда был клик  и вызывает необходимые обработчики для этого случая. Так же работает async/await.